# Почему в моем коде XMLHttpRequest не получает содержимое example.html и не меняет содержимое index.html?

Tags: javascript, html

content_change.js

```
function content_change(content_id)
{
    event.preventDefault();

var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
var url = content_id + '.html'
request.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200)
    {
        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
};
request.open('GET', url);
request.send();}
```

index.html

```
<div id="header">
<a id="menu" onclick="content_change('index')" href="/">Home</a>
<a id="menu" onclick="content_change('example')" href="/example">Example</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
<p>Главная</p>
</div>

<script src="content_change.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

example.html

```
<div id="content" class="content">
<p>Тест</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что вы присваиваете `request.onreadystatechange`не функцию (`request_status`), а результат ее выполнения. `request_status` ничего не возвращает, поэтому это равносильно: `request.onreadystatechange = undefined`

Comment: А вообще `XMLHttpRequest` - прошлый век. Познакомьтесь уже наконец с [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: А что там надо возвращать?

Comment: Ничего не надо возвращать. Я уже написал: вы присваиваете `onreadystatechange` результат выполнения функции, а нужно _саму функцию_.

Comment: О, заработал, всем спасибо!